# Bounded wildcards opposite behavior outside of method parameter

Tags: java, java-11

I am noticing some odd behavior when using bounded wildcards. When I use a bounded wildcard as a method parameter, I see the expected behavior. This code takes a list of `RuntimeException` or its subclasses and prints them:

```java
public static void foo(List<? extends RuntimeException> exceptions) {
    for (RuntimeException ex : exceptions) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

When passing a list of unchecked exceptions, it prints them out without issue.

However, when using a bounded wildcard outside of a method parameter, it seems to apply the opposite of whatever bound is stated (if I write `extends`, it is treated as `super` and vice versa).

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<? extends RuntimeException> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    arr.add(new IllegalArgumentException()); // DOES NOT COMPILE
}
```

The compiler complains:
`java: incompatible types: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.RuntimeException`

When I change `List<? extends RuntimeException>` to `List<? super RuntimeException>`, the code compiles without error when given a subclass of `RuntimeException`. This is the opposite of what I expected to happen. Can anyone explain this behavior?

Edit: no objects can be added to a list declared with a bounded wildcard. The second example fails to compile because it is using the add() method. Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java).

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java) answer your question?

Comment: This is not Java 11 problem as stated in your question, it is expected behaviour as per the docs.

Comment: @Adarsh perfect explanation, thanks!

Comment: You seem to associate the type `List<? extends RuntimeException>` with the explanation "takes a list of RuntimeException or its subclasses". This is somewhat misleading. The shown declaration uses a list with a (nearly) _unknown_ type parameter ... that is what the `?` really means. The only thing you know is that the (still unknown) type parameter must be a subtype of `RuntimeException`. So a `List<RuntimeException>` would fit, but also a `List<IllegalArgumentException>`, or also a `List<UncheckedIOException>`.

Comment: And that means that the compiler cannot allow a call `arr.add(new IllegalArgumentException())`, because it simply cannot know the type parameter with which the list was initialized.

Comment: You still can add `null` to a `List<? extends RuntimeException>`.